# Javascript Print not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Why is this code (Print iFrame) not working in IE.  What's a workable solution?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printTrigger(elementId) {
    var getMyFrame = document.getElementById(elementId);
    getMyFrame.focus();
    getMyFrame.contentWindow.print();
}
</script>
```

Comment: I was trying to use `<link rel="alternate" media="print" href="/documents/ad.pdf" />` but this would not work either do you know whats wrong?

Comment: Just focus to the correct element: `getMyFrame.contentWindow.focus();`

Answer (score 0):

`getMyFrame.print();` should work to print the iframe.

Comment: print does not work on the iframe element, but the iframe's window